# How to Save Changes Done in Bound Controls in VBA/Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba, dao, recordset

I'm setting the New and Save record functions in VBA/Access. When I call the New record function, which is written in the general module, I change the form recordset editmode to dbEditAdd using `.Addnew` (form passed as parameter). At this point, I have no problem. The error is raised after I fill all the textboxes fields and call the function Save record. I basically run the `recordset.Update` and this error raises:

> `# 3021` ("no current record")

All of those textboxes controls are bound to the `form.recordset` fields, they were supposed to write the recordset as I type inside them because they are tied to the recordset fields and, as soon as I call `recordset.Update`, all the pieces of information should be saved in the new recordset without any error. The pieces of information from the bound controls can be saved but always raising that error. I close the error messagebox, open the table and the new record is there. why does this error happen even saving the record in the table?

find the Save record sub:

```
Public Sub Salvar(tela As Form)
    On Error GoTo TratarErro
    Dim registro As DAO.Recordset
    Dim mensagem As String
    Dim retorno As Variant

    Application.Echo False

    Set registro = tela.Recordset

    'Se tiver no modo novo ou edição, cancelar
    If ((registro.EditMode = dbEditAdd) Or (registro.EditMode = dbEditInProgress)) Then
        registro.Update
        registro.Bookmark = registro.LastModified
    Else
        mensagem = MsgBox("Este cadastro não é novo ou não está sendo editado para ser salvo. O sistema precisa estar " & _
            "no modo de novo cadastro ou edição.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Salvar Cadastro")
    End If

    Set registro = Nothing
    Call AtualizarIndicadorRegAtual(tela)

SairErro:
    Application.Echo True
    Exit Sub
TratarErro:
    tela.Undo
    If Not (registro.EditMode = dbEditNone) Then registro.CancelUpdate
    If (registro.RecordCount > 0) Then registro.Bookmark = registro.LastModified
    Set registro = Nothing
    mensagem = MsgBox("Erro: " & Err.Number & Chr(13) + Chr(10) + Chr(10) & "Erro inesperado. Favor, informar ao desenvolvedor do sistema.", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Novo Cadastro")
    Err.Clear
    Call AtualizarIndicadorRegAtual(tela)
    Resume SairErro
End Sub
```

Comment: why so much of code? why don't you use if myForm.dirty then myform.dirty = false >> will update the records when they were modified. capture any errors there. also what is "AtualizarIndicadorRegAtual"

Comment: hello Krish, >why so much of code?< because I will not use form.Dirty. why the question? do you know the answer yes or no? if yes, I'd appreciate your help. >what is "AtualizarIndicadorRegAtual"< I don't think it has to do with the main question but, I can explain, if it helps you somehow: it is for updating a label positioned at the bottom of the form with the current recordset status.

Comment: After reading "i will not use form.dirty" i thought you are going to explain the reason..

Comment: ok. well, using .EditMode I can take more control. this code is just part of the whole recordset control. other things I just can get results thru .EditMode. best regards.